# Gap between top and bottom divs - how to get rid of it?

Tags: html, css, space

How do I get my "TextDiv" to sit right below the "TopDiv"? There's a weird gap between the two divs, is there a CSS reason why it's like that? Thank you

[sorry, had to had to add this extra comment or my thread wouldn't post.]

Comment: You can wrap your `TopRightDiv` and `TopDiv` into one div having `display:flex;`. It would make its child of equal heights.

Comment: Adding display: flex was a little confusing, but I eventually fixed the code, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three separate divs all floating left. The third one is pushed down by the height of the second one.

Try putting the first and third in a div together, and floating a second one next to that.

```
<style>
   #leftWrap { float: left; }
   #topRight { float: left; }
</style>

<div id="leftWrap">
   <div id="topLeft"></div>
   <div id="textDiv"></div>
</div>
<div id="topRight"></div>
```

Comment: Finally got it to work using your code, thank you! Containing the top and third divs together worked. I also needed to surround the TopDiv with a div element. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css

```
.OuterBorder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 120px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
}
.TopDiv {
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
#TextDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
}
.TopRightDiv {
    float: left;
}
.Minibox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:20px;    
}
.MiniImg {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of `TopRightDiv` pushing `TextDiv` to down. Make `TopRightDiv` right align and set the position with `margin-right`.

```
.TopRightDiv {
    float: right;
    margin-right:16px;
}
```

```css
.OuterBorder {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 120px;
 height: 140px;
 float: left;
}
.TopDiv {
 width: 80px;
 height:80px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 float: left;
}
#TextDiv {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 80px;
 float: left;
}
.TopRightDiv {
 float: right;
  margin-right:16px;
}
.Minibox {
 border: 1px solid black;
  width:20px;    
}
.MiniImg {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterBorder" data-menuid="Menu1">
 <a href="#"><img src="#" class="TopDiv"></a>
  
 <div class="TopRightDiv" id="Menu1">
  <a href="#"><div class="Minibox">
   <img src="#" class="MiniImg">
  </div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="Minibox">
   <img src="#" class="MiniImg">
  </div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="Minibox">
   <img src="#" class="MiniImg">
  </div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="Minibox">
   <img src="#" class="MiniImg">
  </div></a>
 </div>
 
  <div id="TextDiv">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to refrain from using the margin property. I got it to work by containing the top and bottom in a single div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.TopRightDiv {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can help

```
.OuterBorder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 120px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    }
.TopDiv {
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
#TextDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
}
.TopRightDiv {
    float: left;
}
.Minibox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:20px;    
}
.MiniImg {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```